# htaccess rule works, but not when applied to the same directory

Tags: .htaccess

If I use the htaccess code:

```
RewriteRule ^test/(.*)/?$ /taxis/index.php?location=$1 [L,QSA,NC,R]
```

and navigation to the link:

http://test.co.uk/test/abcde

the htaccess works and transfers me to: 
http://test.co.uk/taxis/index.php?location=abcde

However, I would like to change the rewrite rule so that it applies to the same directory:

```
^taxis/(.*)/?$ /taxis/index.php?location=$1 [L,QSA,NC,R]
```

but then when i navigate to the link:

http://test.co.uk/taxis/abcde

the link doesn't work and produces:

```
http://test.co.uk/taxis/index.php?location=index.php&location=index.php&location=index.php&location=index.php&location=index.php&location=index.php&location=index.php&location=index.php&location=index.php&location=index.php&location=index.php&location=index.php&location=index.php&location=index.php&location=index.php&location=index.php&location=index.php&location=index.php&location=index.php&location=index.php&location=abcde
```

Do you know how i can tweak this to give me:

http://test.co.uk/taxis/index.php?location=abcde

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the conditions before the rewrite rule that tells it **NOT to rewrite if the URI already points to a resource**, or simply exclude the target of the rule. The rewrite engine continually loops through all the rules until the URI stops changing.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^taxis/(.*)/?$ /taxis/index.php?location=$1 [L,QSA,NC,R]
```

meaning: "If the request *isn't* an existing file, **and** the request *isn't* an existing directory, apply the rule"

Or exclude the rule's target:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/taxis/index\.php$
RewriteRule ^taxis/(.*)/?$ /taxis/index.php?location=$1 [L,QSA,NC,R]
```

Comment: thank you so much Jon, I have been working all day on this and now its finished and working. I didn't realise the rewrite engine continually loops over and over again.